Java HTTClient5.3.1 CLOSE_WAIT() on new application deployment
We are using websphere liberty profile which hosts few applications. All applications runs under the same JVM. Few applications use HTTPClient 5.3.1 to call apis ; we implemented connection pooling as below
ConnectionConfig connConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom()
                    .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setValidateAfterInactivity(validateAfterInactivity, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setTimeToLive(TimeValue.ofSeconds(timeToLive))                 
                    .build();
            
            //Building the custom Request config
            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()                        
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectionRequestTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setResponseTimeout(connectionRequestTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)                
                    .build();
            
            connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                      .setSSLSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
                              .setSslContext(SSLContexts.createSystemDefault())                              
                              .build())
                      .setDefaultSocketConfig(SocketConfig.custom()
                             .setSoTimeout(socketTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)                               
                              .build())                      
                      .setDefaultConnectionConfig(connConfig)               
                      .setMaxConnTotal(maxTotal)
                      .setMaxConnPerRoute(defaultMaxPerRoute)   
                      .build();                         
        
            //Building the http Client
            httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                    .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)     
                    .evictExpiredConnections()                      
                    .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy) 
                    .disableConnectionState()                       
                    .evictIdleConnections(TimeValue.ofSeconds(evictIdleTime))                           
                    .build();       

Connection pooling is working as expected and closing the sockets as expected.
ISSUE: when we deploy one of the applications which was using connection pool previously will start opening new connections but pool orphans few entries in sockets as CLOSE_WAIT.
TCP    <localhostip>:49260    <remoteserverip>:443      CLOSE_WAIT      17068
  TCP    <localhostip>:49362    <remoteserverip>:443      CLOSE_WAIT      17068
  TCP    <localhostip>:49363    <remoteserverip>:443      CLOSE_WAIT      17068
  TCP    <localhostip>:49364    <remoteserverip>:443      CLOSE_WAIT      17068
  TCP    <localhostip>:49365    <remoteserverip>:443      CLOSE_WAIT      17068
  TCP    <localhostip>:49366    <remoteserverip>:443      CLOSE_WAIT      17068

This happens only whenever a new deployment is done. Unfortunately, we cannot kill the JVM process as it used by other applications as well.

Is this the apache htppclient5 bug and any fix available?
Is there anyway the CLOSE_WAIT can be removed from socket level? we are using windows servers.
any other fix is available? we could not do jvm shutdown events as the JVM is shared across other applications.

Thanks

You are likely not closing static client instance(s) or shutting down connection pool(s) upon application deactivation leaving persistent connections kept alive in the pool at the GC mercy.
